# Java spring hibernate.ddl-auto: none property is somehow overrided

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have problem with hibernate.ddl-auto: none in spring. It works fine in development environment and does not execute sql's like drop table. But in production environment same property seems like it's not working. And execute drop and create tables sql's. In application.yaml on production:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
```

I checked this value in application by this:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner initProject() {
    return (args) -> {
        logger.info(env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto")); //this prints "create"
```

So it looks like some internal code changed it value. I run application by this command:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

Comment: Do you have different spring profiles configured?

Comment: I have something like this in application.yaml
profiles:
    active: development
This was in development, in production I have not. But when I copied this to production application.yaml it doesn't change anything

Comment: Do you have embeded database in production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value has to come from somewhere...

You can easily trace this if you have `actuator` enabled

```xml
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

And expose the `env` endpoint via

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: env
```

Then you can visit that endpoint via `/actuator/env`
Here you can even find the location where you have defined the value.

```json
{
  "name": "Config resource 'class path resource [application.yaml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/'",
  "properties": {
  "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto": {
    "value": "none",
    "origin": "class path resource [application.yaml] - 3:25"
},
  "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include": {
  "value": "env",
  "origin": "class path resource [application.yaml] - 9:18"
}...
```

Comment: Thanks for answet. With this I find out that I have in target folder old file application.properties which overrides data from application.yaml. I though this file will be deleted automatically. For this to work I had to remove folder target

Answer (score 0):

The value **none** is undocumented, use **validate** instead.
See also:[What are the possible values of the Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto configuration and what do they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha)

Comment: With validate value it also doesn't change anything. In console it prints "create" and also works like create. That mean it drops all tables and creates it back

Comment: So, probably your property is overridden in production mode. Do you have production-specific profile configuration?